# Can a less fit strain of a virus impose over a fitter one?

Tags: evolution, virology, covid

According to this link, the [Dominant Delta Variant may mutate itself into destruction](https://nypost.com/2021/11/22/dominant-delta-variant-may-mutate-itself-into-extinction-scientists-say/).

> The Delta variant in Japan was highly transmissible and keeping other
> variants out.
>
> But as the mutations piled up, we believe it eventually became a
> faulty virus and it was unable to make copies of itself.

I was told that evolution was about survival of the fittest, and that in the case of virus strains, a more contagious strain would likely increase in frequency relative to a less contagious one. So how can a mutation of the strain Delta which can't replicate or replicate less, increase in frequency relative to the original Delta strain?

Can a less fit strain of a virus impose over a fitter one?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by impose?

Comment: the original coronavirus strain was displaced worldwide by other strains called alpha, delta, etc. The delta, alpha, etc. imposed over the original coronavirus strain

Comment: How are you quantifying 'displaced'? The original strain still exists, presumably, but the other variants are found at higher frequencies. Are you interested in whether it's possible for a less fit strain to reach a higher frequency than another? 'Imposed' doesn't seem to be the correct biological term. I think 'outcompete' is better to use. Sorry if I sound pedantic, but having the correct terminology often is the best way to understand something.

Comment: If I can simplify the question: “Why would a ‘faulty’ mutated strain of the delta variant increase in prevalence relative to the wild type delta variant?” The answer is probably “it’s complicated” and “more information is needed.”

Comment: That's a discusion of semantics, not biology. Displaced can also be used to the Situation you describe. If you partially mover someone from a position you can use the word displaced

Comment: Btw, there are a Lot of researchs using the word displacement to describe the displacement of alpha by beta

Comment: Also note that the term “fitness” has a specific meaning in biology. For a given genotype, relative fitness is the proportion of that genotype in the population gene pool of the next generation. So, by definition, a “less fit” strain cannot overtake the wild type.

Comment: correction, I meant "there are a lot of researchs using the word displacement to describe the displacement of alpha by delta*". typo or corrector

Comment: @acvill "Why would a ‘faulty’ mutated strain of the delta variant increase in prevalence relative to the wild type delta variant?” Even though the question arised with sars-cov-2, I would like to know if there was ever a known case with any virus where a less contagious strain of the same virus could overtake a more contagious one. Because if there wasnt, that means this is also impossible for sars-cov-2

Comment: If one strain of a virus displaces another, or even becomes more prevalent, isn't that strain the fitter one, BY DEFINITION?

Comment: @jamesqf  the question is, how can a strain that's faulty to replicate to the point is going to disappear (cleary not the fitter) impose over another. If a strain replicates little, or not at all, the hosts are going to be taken over by other strains. But the japanese man claims (indirectly) that a faulty to replicate strain took over the non faulty ones.

Comment: @Pablo a less fit strain may outrun a fitter one due to genetic drift, if the infected (sub)population is small... although in this case measuring fitness is problematic. It seems that the variant introduced in Japan, although classified as Delta, had actually low fitness (there is some genetic variation within each variant). Also, a fitter strain may simply become extinct by exterminating all its hosts - not the case of sars-cov-2, but not something unheard of.

Comment: @Pablo: But if a strain mutates in such a way that it can't replicate, or doesn't replicate as well, that mutation has made it less fit.  Conversely, a strain that replicates so well that it eliminates its hosts (perhaps by causing collateral damage), is likewise not fit.  The ideal would be for the virus to reproduce and spread without adversely affecting its host.  Or even benefitting the host, as many of the microorganisms in your microbiome do.

Comment: @jamesqf agree. That's why what that japanese researcher said doesnt make sense to me, and I came here to ask if there is an explanation for what he said.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm not familiar with the concept of genetic drift, for what I read it would seem randomness play a role, but here we are talking about 10 millions viral particles per mililiter per infected person, so it's a population of trillions.

Comment: @Pablo we are not talking about competition within a single host, but about being transmitted to another host and successfully establishing a new infection. The number of people in the cited article is rather small.

Comment: "I find it incredibly difficult to believe that all Covid-19 in Japan has simultaneously and more-or-less in unison, evolved to be a dead end, that seems like a bizarre suggestion.  " I think this sentence means the first man believes all sars-cov-2 particles independently (not from the same parents) mutated in the same direction. Is this even possible?